# listing parent interface of a vlan

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, linux-networking, vlan

I have a setup with a bunch of vlan interfaces on a physical interface.

```
Physical interface: eth1
VLANS on top of this: vlan1, vlan2, vlan3
```

Now, I want to know which is the parent interface of my vlan (for example, here eth1 is the parent interface of these vlans).

I can get this information by running "ip addr show vlan-name" and then in output, I will get vlan1@eth1, but I need to parse the output of this command or by looking at my network config file, parsing it and interpreting it.

Is there another way by which I can get this information without any parsing logic? For example, for bonded interfaces, the information is present in /sys/class/net/ directory and one can simply read files there.

```
# cat /sys/class/net/bond0/bonding/slaves
eth0 eth1
```

Is there a similar path/file available for vlan tagged interfaces? I couldn't figure out if there is some file I can just read without any parsing and extract this information or any command/utility that just gives the parent interface name.

Kindly do let me know if there are other alternatives to this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I didn't find a way without *any* parsing to get the underlying interface, so I give 5 (sometimes just slightly) different ways to get this information. The method 5 added last should be preferred: it uses the JSON output of the `ip` command.

---

There's a symlink having the name of the physical interface:

`$ ls -l /sys/class/net/vlan2`
[...]
`lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root    0 nov.  10 02:12 lower_eth1 -> ../eth1`
[...]
`-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 4096 nov.  10 01:49 uevent`

### Method 1

```
$ echo $(basename $(readlink /sys/class/net/vlan2/lower_*))
eth1
```

---

There's `uevent` that is handy too:

```
$ cat /sys/class/net/vlan2/uevent 
DEVTYPE=vlan
INTERFACE=vlan2
IFINDEX=24
$ cat /sys/class/net/vlan2/lower_*/uevent
INTERFACE=eth1
IFINDEX=22
```

### Method 2

```
$ cat /sys/class/net/vlan2/lower_*/uevent|sed -n 's/^INTERFACE=//p'
eth1
```

---

As root, there are entries in `/proc/net/vlan`:

```
# ls /proc/net/vlan/
config  vlan1  vlan2  vlan3  vlan4  vlan5
# cat /proc/net/vlan/config
VLAN Dev name    | VLAN ID
Name-Type: VLAN_NAME_TYPE_RAW_PLUS_VID_NO_PAD
vlan1          | 1  | eth1
vlan3          | 3  | eth1
vlan4          | 4  | eth1
vlan2          | 2  | eth1
vlan5          | 5  | eth2
```

`# cat /proc/net/vlan/vlan2`
[...]
`Device: eth1`
[...]

### Method 3

```
# awk -F ' *\\| *' '$1 == "vlan2" { print $3 }' /proc/net/vlan/config
eth1
```

### Method 4

```
# sed -n 's/^Device: //p' /proc/net/vlan/vlan2
eth1
```

---

Note that in /sys the other direction is also possible with `upper_*`:

```
$ ls -l /sys/class/net/eth1
```

[...]

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 4096 nov.  10 01:46 uevent
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root    0 nov.  10 02:23 upper_vlan1 -> ../vlan1
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root    0 nov.  10 02:18 upper_vlan2 -> ../vlan2
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root    0 nov.  10 02:23 upper_vlan3 -> ../vlan3
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root    0 nov.  10 02:23 upper_vlan4 -> ../vlan4

$ sed -n 's/^INTERFACE=//p' /sys/class/net/eth1/upper_*/uevent
vlan1
vlan2
vlan3
vlan4
```

---

Since 2017 `ip` (which uses the [(rt)netlink](https://manpages.debian.org/manpages/rtnetlink.7) socket interface to communicate with the kernel) [got a JSON output](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/network/iproute2/iproute2.git/commit/?id=5df607725928d532a3b7e5095c04e943b2c3ce7f) for many of its subcommands to ease its scriptability. Together with the [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) command this is probably the best choice:

### Method 5

```
$ ip -json link show vlan1 | jq -r '.[]|.link'
eth1

$ ip -json link show type vlan | jq -j '
    .[] | (.ifname," ∈ ",.link,"\n")
'
vlan1 ∈ eth1
vlan2 ∈ eth1
vlan3 ∈ eth1
```

Comment: Well OP already had the best method: the `ip` command. When using the newer JSON output and `jq` this gives: `ip -json link show vlan1 | jq -r '.[]|.link'` => `eth1`. or `ip -json link show type vlan | jq -j '.[]|(.ifname,"∈",.link,"\n")'` to display all. This should be more reliable